# Command line utility to read vCalendar files

Tags: command-line, calendar

I use alpine to read mails, and occasionally get emails from people with vCalendar files in attachment. Is there a command line utility that reads and displays vCalendar files?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I just googled and found [vcal](http://waynemorrison.com/software/vcal), a perl script for displaying vcal files. According to the [man page](http://tewok.com/software/vcal-man.html) it should do exactly what you need.

There is also [gcalcli](https://github.com/insanum/gcalcli) a command line interface for google calendar which allows you to manage your google calendar. This may allow you to add events you received directly to your existing calendar.